# What is the difference between double negation and checking if the variable is truthy directly?

Tags: javascript, negation

I noticed my colleagues are writing code with double negation in conditions, for example:

```
else if(colType == 'link'){
    value = !!data ? $(data).attr('href') : '';
}
```

In cases like this, is there a chance that the boolean result of `data` can be different from `!!data`?

Comment: In that specific case, no, there's no difference whatsoever between `!!data ?` and `data ?`. See the linked question's answers for details. You only need the double bang (`!!`) when you need the result to be a boolean (`true` or `false`), specifically, not when just having truthy/falsy is good enough.